# How to await firebase to start, avoiding Error: "Client is offline" on React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, expo

I need help retrieving firebase data in React Native, using expo.
This code works fine when I refresh the app, but when it first starts, it throws an error:
`Error: Error: Client is offline.`
Maybe I need to do it async and await, I have tried some ways, but no success.

```
 componentDidMount = async () => {
    var radioFireData = null;
    const { names } = this.props;
    const dbRef = ref(db, "records/");
    get(child(dbRef, "flap/"))
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          radioFireData = snapshot.val();
          this.setState({ checked: radioFireData[names] });
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is... Maybe I can help someone.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const { names } = this.props;
    const reference = ref(db, "records/" + "/flap/");
    onValue(
      reference,
      (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({ checked: data[names] });
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
  };
```